# My Windows lock screen language won't budge

Tags: windows, lockscreen

I recently refreshed my Windows due to a virus. Ever since then, my lock screen date language is stuck on Arabic. I've gone to the Control Panel, and changed the registry keys to 'en-US' as well. It's still showing me the date in Arabic. What should I do?

Sorry for the absence of a screenshot. Guide me with that too so I can post an image here for your ease.

Comment: Nope. Windows 8. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control panel - Regional - Administrative - Copy Settings - Welcome screen.

Comment: in that case some of your system files got replaced by the virus, you cant be sure to get your virus-free windows back until you actually format your harddrive and reinstall windows.